# Can we append a string variable to ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementbyId(data))?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append a string variable into the `ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))`. append(Content)
I tried the following code,but it didn't worked out.

```
var Content = '<input type="number" name="estimatedQty" placeholder="Estmated quantity"  step="0.5" /><input type="number" name="estmatedtime" placeholder="Estimated Time" />';
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)).append(Content);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first create the child element and then you can append content to it.

```
var Content = '<input type="number" name="estmatedtime" placeholder="Estimated Time" />';

var input = document.createElement('input');
tagetElement.appendChild(input);

$('#targetElement input').append('Content').attr({
    type:"number", 
    name:"estimatedQty",
    placeholder: "Estmated quantity",
    step: "0.5"
});
```

/Zorken17

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve here but because you're using jquery better if you use Jquery funciton `append()` :

```
$(ev.target).append(Content);
```

Hope this helps.